# Windward Document Generation - PDF Copy Protected

Tags: pdf, drm, copy-protection, windward

In our application, we generate a few reports and documents through Windward. The documents are generated based on specific user conditions and the user is able to download the document.

As part of a new requirement, we would like to enable copy protection of the generated PDF -- basically, users would not be able to Copy the contents of the document.

Is there anyway we can achieve this through Windward? Or do we have to integrate with external third party software like LockLizard or Win2PDF?

We did think of converting the document to an image and recreating the PDF but this is unacceptable as the document formatting became off the mark.

Appreciate any insights or alternate solutions.

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 0):

Windward does this. If you're using the Java engine use the following calls ([javadoc](http://www.windward.net/javadoc/index.html)):

```
ProcessPdfAPI.setOwnerPassword()
ProcessPdfAPI.setUserPassword()
```

For the .NET engine use the following calls ([api docs](http://www.windward.net/dotnethelp/webframe.html)):

```
ReportPdf.OwnerPassword
ReportPdf.Security
ReportPdf.UserPassword
```

Is this what you need?